# Adicionar Parametros na URL do Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, url-amigável, url-rewrite, plugin-wordpress

Eu tenho um plugin que gerencia links no Wordpress, com imagens e textos fingindo ser artigos relacionados, todos são links externos. (Tipo Taboola).

Eu gostaria de adicionar no final dos Links alguns parametros. Ex:

Link ==> outrosite.com.br

Eu quero adicionar agora o seguinte:

Link ==> outrosite.com.br?src=urldinamicadowordpress

Assim eu consigo saber a origem desses cliques e qual o artigo está convertendo mais cliques.

Se possível, ainda adicionar se o click veio de mobile ou Desktop

Link ==> outrosite.com.br?src=urldinamicadowordpress|mobile

Link ==> outrosite.com.br?src=urldinamicadowordpress|desktop

Código do Redirecionamento

```
add_action('init', 'count_clicks');
function count_clicks()
    {
    global $wpdb;
    if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'count') {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $tableName = $wpdb->prefix . 'post_related_meta';

    $meta = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("select meta_clicks, meta_link from $tableName where meta_id = %s", $id));
    $meta = $meta[0];

    $wpdb->update($wpdb->prefix."post_related_meta", array(
        'meta_clicks' => (int)$meta->meta_clicks+1,
    ), array(
        'meta_id' => $_GET['id']
    ),
        array(
            '%d'
        )
    );

    $redirect = $meta->meta_link;
    header("Location: $redirect");
    exit;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como fazer isso depende um pouco de como são gerados os links para os artigos externos. Se você tem controle deles, basta colocar algo assim:

```
$url_dinamica = $_REQUEST['REQUEST_URI'];
$query = http_build_query( array( 'src' => $url_dinamica ) );
```

e colocar ao final do link existente:

```
<a href="http://example.com/?<?php echo esc_attr( $query ); ?>">Link</a>
// imprime http://example.com/?src=seusite.com.br/pagina/do/link
```

Para distinguir entre mobile e desktop você pode usar a função nativa [`wp_is_mobile()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_is_mobile/)

```
$url_dinamica = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url_dinamica .= '|' . ( wp_is_mobile() ? 'mobile' : 'desktop' );
```

Essa solução só funciona se não tiver cache completo das páginas. Caso tenha você vai precisar de uma solução em javascript.

**EDIT**

Atualizando de acordo com o código adicionado. Pra funcionar basta colocar a query ao final de `$meta->meta_link;`:

```
$redirect = rtrim( $meta->meta_link, '/') .'/?'. $query;
header("Location: $redirect");
exit();
```

O `rtrim()` ali serve pra garantir que não vamos ter barras duplicadas ao final da URL. Estou considerando que $meta->meta_link nunca tem parâmetros, é sempre uma URL simples. Se tiver é preciso alterar esse código pra testar por parâmetros e usar `?` ou `&` adequadamente.

Comment: Entendi, eu fiz um teste aqui e isso realmente funciona! Muito Obrigado!

Mas, no meu plugin acho que não vai poder ser assim, pelo simples motivo de ter um redirecionamento. A não ser que de pra passar esses parametros entre urls.

URL que conta o Clique e Redireciona: 
http://meusite.com.br/?action=count&id=1&src=testeparam

Direciona para: meusite.com.br

Eu queria que ficasse: meusite.com.br?src=testeparam

pegando isso da primeira url que faz a contagem dos cliques.

Comment: dá pra fazer se você conseguir interceptar esse redirecionamento. Coloca na pergunta o código onde o redirecionamento é feito que eu atualizo.

Comment: Obrigado Ricardo! Atualizaei o Código pra Você!

Comment: Atualizei a resposta @AndersonCosta, veja se resolve.

Comment: It Works! Show de Bola Ricardo! Vlw